# how to know from which site it is safe to download pkgs

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

usually I download from redhat repository all rpms that I need

one rpm is - `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm`

location - `http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/44308336/dir/scientific_linux_7/com/java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm.html`

is available in site -  http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3

but not defined in redhat site!

**my question  - is it safe enough to download rpm's from this site?**

Reason - we are worry to get virus in files

Comment: Ultimately, that's for you to decide if you deem a site "safe". If it's not the official repo, it's not official.

Comment: what is your private opinion on - rpm.pbone.net site?

Comment: I don't know the site. It is _probably_ safe, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I do see the packages in rhel repo: https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel/1.8.0.222.b10-1.el8/x86_64/fd431d51/package